# Как автоматизировать обновление кода на C# на сервере с помощью GitHub?

Tags: c#, git, github, asp.net-core

Нужно автоматизировать обновление кода на сервере, что б я изменял код у себя на компьютере, затем залил на GitHub, а затем подал команду серверу -"Обновись"- он закачает код и запустится обновлённым.
Как такое реализовать?

Comment: а не проще настроить публикацию при билде? VS это точно умеет, за другие IDE не знаю.

Comment: @rdorn а как сервер закачает потом данные к себе?

Comment: я и мел ввиду публикацию собранного сервера. А исходники пусть остаются исходниками. Ну или учите сервер подключаться к GitHub и делать Checkout в подходящую папку

Comment: В цепочке "закачает исходники с гитхаба и запустится обновлённым" пропущен логический шаг "скомпилирует исходники". Плохо продумали, не взлетит.

Comment: Это вполне умеет например https://appharbor.com/

Comment: bitbucket вроде такое умеет для .net core, bitbucket pipelines называется фича

Comment: Кратко: нужен сервер непрерывной интеграции, который будет реагировать на коммиты, компилировать код и деплоить новую версию приложения. GitLab CI, Travis CI, Circle CI, Bitbucket Pipelines, Jenkins, Appharbor...